What are possible causes for an energy meter and a inverter not talking to each other?
I'm trying to wire up a Solax X3-Hybrid (Gen 2) inverter to CHINT DTSU-666 Energy meter over RS485 so that the Inverter can make use of the BESS more intelligently depending on the household energy draw.
After consulting the relevant manuals (inverter, meter), I've connected a single twisted pair of a CAT5 ethernet cable from pins 1&2 on the inverter to pins 24 and 25 on the meter.
I've verified that:

the meter is compatible with the inverter
the Ct, data protocol and baud rate are set according to the Solax guide for a newer version of the meter

I've also tried:

swapping the two wires

However, once you enable the meter function on the inverter, it shows "meter fault". In newer models there is supposedly a debug functionality to narrow down what the issue is, but no such luck for me, so I'm left to eliminating potential causes manually.
Being the EE noob that I am, I can't help but think there's some simple wiring / EE issue that might be at play here, and here are things I haven't ruled out, and pose as questions to the community:

I understand CAT5 cables have 100Ω impedance, whereas RS485 expects 120Ω. My impression is that this is usually close enough and should "just work". Is this a poor assumption, given the cable runs ~30m (100 feet)?
Relatedly, I understand best practice suggests having a 120Ω termination resistor. Is this likely to be the missing piece of the puzzle, or is it not strictly neccessary?
The said ethernet cable is run in an underground conduit alongside multiple AC cables that connect to the batteries. Is EMI from these likely to be an issue?

Altogether then - what is my best course of debugging here? Am I missing something obvious?

Nothing is mentioned in the inverter manual about Modbus Which is the meter protocol. How did you verify that the two are compatible?

@ChesterGillon the inverter has a separate "meter interface", where the RS485 pins are 1 and 2, see page 41.

@MrGerber I was referring to https://kb.solaxpower.com/solution/detail/ff8080818407e2a701840a15af480028 - this list mentions DDS not DTS in the model, but several of their instruction videos do use the DTS one with the same inverter (but a newer gen).

@Max Sorry, I deleted my incorrect comment before your reply after realising was looking at the wrong section of the manual.

Well you need to know if the devices implement termination or if you need external termination. Also RS-485 is not a two wire interface, the two wires need also a shared ground potential between devices. Unless the devices already share a same refetence potential for the RS-485 bus, like via mains earth, you need to pass the ground between the two devices as well.

Can you scope the signals with 2 identical 10:1 probes on Ch1-Ch2?  1st confirm you can get a flat line looking at any one signal on both probes in A-B mode.

compare both ends, If 20% Z mismatch will degrade SNR +/10% which could still be 20 dB SNR and can be error-free. So check the Vcm and Vdiff min.  30 m cable will reflect 100 ns at end and 200 ns to the source then report back & edit Q.

Missing termination is a problem on long cables, but if your SNR is >=10:1 that is a good start.

How do you set serial communication parameters, like baud rate??

@ScottSeidman I was referring to the baud rate setting on the meter (see manual p.9)

Have you tried swapping the RS485 bus wires? RS485 A and B are poorly defined in terms of polarity. One way works, the other doesn’t. No damage is done if they are reversed.

@Kartman yeah I do believe I tried that, will add to post!
